# Small generator for classical Schnorr signatures?

Tags: schnorr-signature

I'm implementing classical Schnorr signatures for real-world use. By "classical," I mean that the operations occur in a finite group, with no elliptic curves.

I'm following [Schnorr signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) and [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group) at Wikipedia, and some academic papers.

After choosing $p=qr+1$ with $p$ and $q$ prime I need to calculate a suitable "generator" $g$.

As explained on the Wikipedia page, I set $h=2$ and try to see if $h^r \textrm{mod } p$ is different from 1 (it always has been so far) and that value becomes $g$.

The trouble is, $g$ is (logarithmically) about as large a number as $p$ when chosen this way.

Is there a way to choose a smaller $g$ so that less parameter data needs to be passed around?

If I understand correctly, any $g$ s.t. $g^q=1 \textrm{ mod }p$ ought to work (provided, of course, $g \ne 1$). It's easy to see why $2^r$ works; it's because $(2^r)^q=2^{rq}=2^{p-1}$ which is 1 by Fermat's little theorem.

But can a smaller $g$ be derived somehow?

Comment: Just try small candidates for g. ​ ​

Comment: Can you just set $r = 2$?  In just about every case I've encountered, $g = 3$ will work in that case.

Comment: @Bristol It's been a while since I was fooling around with Schnorr signatures, but IIRC setting a larger $r$ increases the security level at a lower cost than just increasing $q$.

Comment: @Bristol: problem is, the signature has the size of $q$, and $p$ must be large, thus we must use a large $r$ if we want short signatures. And, as stated in [that answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72804/555), we can use a small $h$, but AFAIK not a small $g$.

Answer (score 1):

[FIPS 186-4 appendix A.2](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=40) gives an algorithm to generate $g$. They are not talking about Schnor signatures but apparently DSA uses just the same kind of finite cyclic groups.

The algorithm really just tries random $1 < h < p-1$ until it finds an $h$ that fulfills $h^r \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Apparently the probability to find such an $h$ is not too small.

*Fermat's little theorem* states that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for any prime $p$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ with $p \nmid a$.

Thus, with $h<p$ you automatically get $p \nmid h$ and therefore $g^q \equiv h^{rq} \equiv h^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

I guess the goal cannot be to find a $g$ with a small bit width to save data. As you calculate $g = h^r \text{ mod } p$ with $r$ being random (uniformly distributed), the possible values for $g$ should be uniformly distributed as well.